# If G is a finitely generated group with vcd(G) finite, is vcd(H) finite for H, where H is an automorphism group of G?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, mapping-class-groups, automorphism-groups, free-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\vcd{vcd}\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Inn{Inn}\DeclareMathOperator\Out{Out}$Here I mean $\vcd(G)$ to be the virtual cohomological dimension of $G$. Some possible examples of what I mean by $H$ are $H=\Aut(G)$, $\Inn(G)$ or $\Out(G)$. I could extend this to other natural, more topological examples as well.

I've wondered about this and wondered if anyone actually speculated about this since the work in the 70s and 80s studying this problem where G is either a surface group (Harer, Penner, Thurston, etc.) or a free group (Culler, Vogtmann, Charney?, Bestvina, etc.). Of course we have the work of Borel, Serre and others for arithmetic groups, where G could be free abelian, or probably polycyclic-by-finite.

I would reframe and expand this question as follows:
Let $G$ have $\vcd(G)$ finite so we have a finite dimensional model $X$ of $K(G,1)$.
How can we construct a suitably good finite dimensional model $Y$ of $K(\Aut(G),1)$, for example?

As a side question, are there groups $G$ with $\vcd(G)$ finite but infinitely generated center $Z(G)$? What happens with $\Inn(G)=G/Z(G)$ then?

Comment: I just realized that, to simplify things regarding torsion and finite index subgroups, we may as well assume G is torsion free to start off here.

Comment: Do you know the Mikhailova's construction of f.g. subgroups of products of two free groups?

Comment: No I don't. How would it be relevant and do you have a reference?

Comment: OK, later......

Comment: For the last question, i.e., are there finitely generated groups with finite vcd but non-finitely generated center, the answer is yes. You can take "Abels's groups" Ab_n, which are the groups of n-by-n upper triangular matrices over Z[1/p] (for any prime p) whose first and last diagonal entries are 1. For n>2, Ab_n is finitely generated, but the center is the copy of Z[1/p] "in the top right" so it's not fin. gen.

Comment: The related question of whether a group $G$ of type F can have a $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ (or $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$) with infinite vcd seems harder. The examples given in Moishe Kohan's answer are finite dimensional, but never finitely presented. It may be possible to use fibre products to get finitely presented examples, but higher finiteness properties seem out of reach to these techniques. Maybe there's some other kind of example known?

Comment: @HJRW: I am curious, what about Baumslag-Solitar groups? Some of them have their automorphism groups not finitely generated. Are they sufficiently big to have an infinite vcd?

Comment: @HJRW Finitely presentability can be salvaged from Moishe Kohan's answer, but this likely sacrifices finite dimensionality: Take the HNN-extension $H=\langle G, t\mid t^{-1}xt=x,\:x\in N\rangle$. Then the automorphisms $\phi_x: g\mapsto g, t\mapsto x^{-1}tx$ for $x\in N$ gives an embedding of $Q$ into $\operatorname{Out}(H)$.

Comment: @ADL: I don't quite follow you (perhaps there's a typo?). Surely at the very least $\phi_x$ should be parametrised by the elements of $Q$ (or $G$) rather than $N$? Sorry for being slow on the uptake!

Comment: @HJRW Sorry, yes, parameterised by $G$. Then each $\phi_x$ for $x\in N$ is trivial, so this gives a map $Q\to\operatorname{Aut}(H)\to\operatorname{Out}(H)$. These maps can then be shown to be injective here (the map to $\operatorname{Aut}$ is pretty clearly injective, by for example Britton's Lemma, while the map to $\operatorname{Out}$ is also injective as none of these $\phi_x$ are inner because, as $G$ has trivial centre and $N\neq G$, no inner automorphism of $H$ fixes every $g\in G$).

Comment: @ADL: I see it now. Nice! I did look at your paper about HNN extensions of triangle groups when trying to figure out if there was a way to provide examples with base groups of type F.

Comment: @Agenevois Given the Baumslag-Solitar group is a 1-relator group, IIRC by standard theorems it's going to have a torsion free subgroup of finite index and it should have finite vcd( at most 2). Do you have a reference for the automorphism group or do I need to prove it as an exercise for the reader? ; )

Comment: @Mike The standard example of a Baumslag-Solitar group with non-finitely generated (outer) automorphism group is $BS(2, 4)$, due to Collins and Levine in the 1980s ("Automorphisms and Hopficity of certain Baumslag-Solitar groups" Arch. Math. (1983)); Levitt gave a geometric reason for this non-finite generation in a 2007 G&T paper [(link)](https://msp.org/gt/2007/11-1/gt-v11-n1-p08-s.pdf). Theorem 5.2 of this gives a positive answer to your question in the "nice" case of (Generalised) Baumslag-Solitar groups with no $BS(1, n)$ subgroups, $n>1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, it is Rips' and not Mikhailova's construction: I should not comment when I am half-asleep.

Let me start with the Rips construction.

Let $Q$ be a finitely presented group. Rips in [1] constructed $C'(1/\lambda)$-[small cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory) groups $G$ (with arbibtarily large $\lambda$) and normal finitely generated subgroups $N< G$ such that $G/N\cong Q$. For $\lambda\ge 7$ the group $G$ will be hyperbolic.

A nice exposition of the Rips construction and its generalizations can be found in these two blog-posts: [here](https://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/the-rips-construction-i) and [here](https://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/the-rips-construction-ii). Actually, the Rips construction is quite flexible and one can make choices so that no defining relator of $G$ is a proper power; hence, the presentation complex of $G$ is aspherical. In particular, $G$ is torsion-free and is 2-dimensional. The subgroup $N$, therefore, is also 2-dimensional. However, the group $Q$ can be taken to have infinite virtual cohomological dimension.

We, thus, obtain a finitely generated 2-dimensional group $N$ such that $Out(N)$ contains $Q$ and thus has infinite vcd.

I am not sure how to find examples where $Aut$ has infinite vcd.

[1] *Rips, E.*, [**Subgroups of small cancellation groups**](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/14.1.45), Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 14, 45-47 (1982). [ZBL0481.20020](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0481.20020).

**Edit.** A modification of the Rips construction in [2] yields examples where $Out(N)\cong Q$ even though it is not need for your question.

[2] *Bumagin, Inna; Wise, Daniel T.*, [**Every group is an outer automorphism group of a finitely generated group.**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2004.12.033), J. Pure Appl. Algebra 200, No. 1-2, 137-147 (2005). [ZBL1082.20021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1082.20021).

Comment: Thanks. How do you get to Out(N)≅Q, though?

Comment: @Mike: no nontrivial element of $G$ commutes with all elements of $N$ (by hyperbolicity).

Comment: I see why the map $G\to Aut(N)$ induces an injective map $Q\to Out(N)$, but is it really always surjective? In any case, injectivity is enough to ensure $Out(N)$ has infinite vcd once $Q$ does, as desired (and maybe $Q$ really is isomorphic to $Out(N)$ and I'm just being dense).

Comment: Oh, this should be corrected. I only claim injectivity which suffices.